# Currency field to words

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

I got this apex code for converting numbers to word but want to display this in VF  using standard controller and extension.

```
public class NumberToWord1 {

    public NumberToWord1(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

    public String english_number { get; set; }

      static String[] to_19 = new string[]{ 'zero', 'one',  'two', 'three', 'four',  'five',  'six',  
     'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten',  'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen',  
     'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen' };  
   static String[] tens = new string[]{ 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'};  
   static String[] denom = new string[]{ '',  
     'thousand',   'million',     'billion',    'trillion',    'quadrillion',  
     'quintillion', 's!xtillion',   'septillion',  'octillion',   'nonillion',  
     'decillion',  'undecillion',   'duodecillion', 'tredecillion',  'quattuordecillion',  
      's!xdecillion', 'septendecillion', 'octodecillion', 'novemdecillion', 'vigintillion' };  
    // convert a value < 100 to English.    
   public static String convert_nn(integer val) {  
      if (val < 20)  
        return to_19[val];  
     if(val == 100)  
          return 'One Hundred';  
      for (integer v = 0; v < tens.size(); v++) {  
       String dcap = tens[v];  
       integer dval = 20 + 10 * v;  
      if (dval + 10 > val) {  
         if (Math.Mod(val,10) != 0)  
            return dcap + ' ' + to_19[Math.Mod(val,10)];  
         return dcap;  
       }      
      }  
      return 'Should never get here, less than 100 failure';  
   }  
   // convert a value < 1000 to english, special cased because it is the level that kicks   
    // off the < 100 special case. The rest are more general. This also allows you to  
   // get strings in the form of "forty-five hundred" if called directly.  
    public static String convert_nnn(integer val) {  
      String word = '';  
      integer rem = val / 100;  
     integer mod = Math.mod(val,100);  
     if (rem > 0) {  
       word = to_19[rem] + ' hundred';  
       if (mod > 0) {  
         word += ' ';  
       }  
     }  
      if (mod > 0) {  
       word += convert_nn(mod);  
      }  
     return word;  
   }  
    public static String english_number(long val) {  
      if (val < 100) {  
        return convert_nn(val.intValue());  
      }  
     if (val < 1000) {  
        return convert_nnn(val.intValue());  
     }  
      for (integer v = 0; v < denom.size(); v++) {  
       integer didx = v - 1;  
        integer dval = (integer)Math.pow(1000, v);  
    if (dval > val) {  
         integer mod = (integer)Math.pow(1000, didx);  
        integer l = (integer) val / mod;  
          integer r = (integer) val - (l * mod);  
          String ret = convert_nnn(l) + ' ' + denom[didx];  
          if (r > 0) {  
            ret += ', ' + english_number(r);  
          }  
          return ret;  
        }  
      }  
      return 'Should never get here, bottomed out in english_number';  
    }  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your controller extension will need to let the standard controller know to query the field that you want to display and also call the `convert_nn` formatting method on the value. One way to to that is this:

```
private MySObject__c sob;

public NumberToWord1(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
    if (!Test.isRunningTest()) {
        sc.addFields(new String[] {
                String.valueOf(MySObject__c.NumericField__c)
                });
    }
    this.sob = (MySObject__c) sc.getRecord();
}

public String english_number {
    get {
        if (sob.NumericField__c != null) {
            return convert_nn(sob.NumericField__c.intValue());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The Visualforce would be:

```
<apex:page standardController="MySObject__c" extensions="NumberToWord1">
    ...
    <apex:outputText value="{!english_number}"/>
    ...
</apex:page>
```